# Generating pure colors of equal brightness (for display on LEDs)

Tags: algorithm, colors, led

I have some RGB LEDs, and I want to have them display random colors.

My first approach was to pick a random hue *h* from 0-360, create an HSV color of the form (*h*, 1, 1), and then convert from HSV to RGB using [the algorithm given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV).  This almost does what I want, but not quite.

The problem is that the LED can appear to be brighter or dimmer, depending on the hue.  I want it to always appear to be the same brightness, regardless of the hue.

So, for example, blue will be (0, 0, 1) in RGB space, but cyan will be (0, 1, 1).  If we make the simplifying assumption that all three primaries are equally bright, then cyan is twice as bright as blue.

What I want is something where blue will be (0, 0, 1) in RGB space, and cyan will be (0, 0.5, 0.5), so that the sum of the primaries is always 1.0.

I can hack something together fairly easily with an algorithm like this:

- Pick a value *x* between 0 and 1.
- Pick one of the three primaries, and set it to *x*.
- Pick one of the two remaining primaries, and set it to 1 - *x*.
- Set the third primary to 0.

My question is: Is there a more principled way to do this?  Is there some color space that behaves the way I want it to?

**Conclusion:** @Vincent van der Weele had the important insight that I needed to normalize.  And @Stefan Haustein's luma is another way to say the same thing, while also adding in different weights for the different primaries.  However, those particular weights didn't work in my situation.  Experimentally, I picked weights of 0.3, 0.25, and 0.2 for R, G, and B.  And also experimentally, I picked a gamma of 2.0 (as opposed to the 2.8 I had originally been using).  This still isn't perfect, but it's a lot better than before.  I guess this is just naturally messy.

Comment: Can't you just normalise the output as a post-processing step by dividing each `R`, `G` and `B` by `R+G+B`?

Comment: While this has a programming component, the whole subject of color and luminance/brightness matching are a different field which also brings in receptors of the eye and that whole field where whole books and papers are written. I don't think this is an appropriate SO question.

Comment: The problem is that (0,1,0) is quite bright, but (0,0,1) is quite dark.

Comment: @MattTimmermans that's true, but in your head you already compensate for that. If you make the green and blue lights equivalent by any measure of lightness, the green light will look unnaturally dark.

Comment: You need to measure/estimate/calibrate illumination response for each LED. Then linearize the brightness value for Each LED (so your interval `<0.0,1.0>` will change possibly non linearly for each LED differently). But as was mentioned in the comments this is huge task with entire industry around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take the luma for the darkest color of your spectrum (= blue, 0.0722). Then scale the calculated RGB values so that the resulting luma matches this value. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)

```
luma = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b;
// factor * luma = 0.0722
factor = 0.0722 / luma;
r *= factor;
g *= factor;
b *= factor;
```

P.S. With your simplifying assumption, this would be

```
luma = (r + g + b) / 3.0;
factor = 1.0 / (3.0 * luma);
r *= factor;
g *= factor;
b *= factor;
```

Normalizing the total brightness to the brightness of a single component (1/3)

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding something here.  For many colors (yellow, for example) the blue component will be zero.  So that would result in a divide by zero.

Comment: I was referring to the darkest color you want to show, a constant. All colors will need to have this brightness if you want the brightness to be constant.

Comment: p.s. Have added a code snippet to illustrate this better

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.  However, when I apply your formula, my greens are super-dim compared to the reds and blues.  Is it possible that the weights appropriate for television are not the right weights to use for an RGB LED?

Comment: @user31708 LEDs are not linear so `(0.0,0.2,0.0)+(0.0,0.2,0.0)!=(0.0,0.4,0.0)` and the TV is linearized so the equations will not match ... There are quite a few things screwing this: Are you using linear DAC?  do you got Linear(ized) LEDs? Do they have the same brightness? my bet is NO for each of the questions

Comment: I'd just tweak the weights until the primary colors seem to have the same brightness. I'd only care about taking gamma into account when you are happy with the primary colors but the mixed colors are still off.

Comment: @Spektre, I'm using PWM, not a DAC.

Comment: @user31708 `PWM + LED + low pass filter (human sight)` is **DAC** on its own. **PWM** usually provides linear power output unless you got some other non linearity present like constant current supply in the LED driver. The problem with un-handled non linearity is when you finally adjust colors at some brightness then in another brightness levels the color change.

Comment: @Spektre a DAC wouldn't provide consistent or linear output like PWM does. An RGB LED should be close enough to equal output on each primary, otherwise the combination of all wouldn't be white; I'm sure they control for this in manufacturing. And the non-linearity you speak of is gamma.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, the combination colors yellow, cyan, and magenta are brighter than the primaries red, green, and blue. You can see this in a simple plot of the hues generated by HSV (I belive HSL would look the same):

[image: HSV in sRGB]

They're brighter, but not *twice* as bright. That's because the eye responds to light with a [power-law function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevens%27s_power_law). Taking the intensity to [the power of 0.43](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction#Power_law_for_video_display) most closely approximates what your eye sees; this implies that yellow, cyan, and magenta only appear 1.35 times brighter.

There's one other factor to consider. The HSV formula is producing sRGB values, which have a [gamma correction factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) of about 2.2 - the values are not linear with respect to the amount of light produced. Your LEDs probably *are* linear, so they will look different:

[image: HSV linearized]

Yuck! Obviously the values that drive your LED will need to be in a linear color space, not sRGB.

To keep a constant brightness, the sum of all the colors in a power-law space will need to be constant. You can accomplish this by applying the power law to the linear r,g,b intensities, then scaling the r,g,b over the sum. Taking the inverse of the power law restores the values back to linear RGB.

Here's some actual Python code and the resulting image. The r,g,b values were converted from linear to sRGB for producing the image file, but I left that out for clarity. The `srgb2.from_sRGB` function I wrote myself based on the [standard sRGB linearity conversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation).

```
r,g,b = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(angle/360, 1.0, 1.0)
r,g,b = srgb2.from_sRGB([r*255,g*255,b*255])
gamma = .43
r,g,b = r**(1/gamma), g**(1/gamma), b**(1/gamma)
t = r + g + b
r = r / t
g = g / t
b = b / t
r,g,b = r**gamma, g**gamma, b**gamma
```

[image: HSV normalized]

No more bright spots!

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of gamma.  I was intentionally leaving it out of my question (along with the different weights of red, green, and blue) to focus on the fact that cyan is lighting two LEDs while blue is only lighting one.  I'm performing gamma correction after all of the other steps.  However, I'm using a [gamma of 2.8](https://learn.adafruit.com/led-tricks-gamma-correction/the-longer-fix).  So your gamma is less than 1, while my gamma is more than 1; it seems that one of us has it backwards.

Comment: @user31708 yes, I was going to double-check my math later when I had a little more time. But it's obvious that lighting two colors needs less intensity than lighting one, it's just a matter of coming up with the exact amount.

Comment: @user31708 I just rewrote the answer from scratch, I think you'll find it both easier to follow and more satisfactory in the results.

Comment: @MarkRansom Nice answer +1. Btw to respond to your comment DAC provide also linear output but it must be properly output for LED and LED LASERs constant current supply is used instead of driving Voltage So in the result the Power is linear regardless of the non linearity. I did not mean GAMMA by the LED non linearity between each other. Each Band color LED have different response to power and must be linearized so they match between others. That is done by the LED driver or it is inbuild into the LEDs directly. But we do not know if OP's  LEDs have this properly done (So it is thing to check)